# mod_rewrite query. Changing files to Folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to update the URL to show a folder name and not the individual file.
I believe this can be done using **mod_rewrite** but I can't seem to get it working. This is on a local network device and not a public server. PHP is version 4.

running :

```
<?php
print_r(apache_get_modules());
?>
```

I get:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => core
    [1] => mod_access
    [2] => mod_auth
    [3] => mod_include
    [4] => mod_log_config
    [5] => mod_env
    [6] => mod_setenvif
    [7] => mod_ssl
    [8] => prefork
    [9] => http_core
    [10] => mod_mime
    [11] => mod_status
    [12] => mod_autoindex
    [13] => mod_asis
    [14] => mod_cgi
    [15] => mod_negotiation
    [16] => mod_dir
    [17] => mod_imap
    [18] => mod_actions
    [19] => mod_userdir
    [20] => mod_alias
    [21] => mod_rewrite
    [22] => mod_so
    [23] => sapi_apache2
)
```

Which suggests mod_rewrite is enabled.

My directory structure is :
10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments

Within in payments I have numberous **.php** files, instead of each one showing as filename.php in the address bar, I'd prefer to just display **`http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments`**

In the payments folder I've created a **.htaccess** file and included :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^*\.php$ /local/accounts/payments
```

But nothing changed in the address bar. Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

UPDATE

Sorry I don't think I've been very clear.

I want to change

```
http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments/bacs.php
```

to

```
http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments
```

or any php file in payments to just show payments NOT the file name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, You want that url

```
http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments/rent
```

rewrites to

```
http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments/rent.php
```

In this case:

```
RewriteRule ^local/accounts/payments/(.*)$ local/accounts/payments/$1.php
```

Comment: Hi. The other way round.
`http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments/rent.php` rewrites to `http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments/rent`  or if possible rewrites to `http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments`  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try in your htaccess file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^local/accounts/payments/([^/]+)$ /local/accounts/payments/$1.php [NC,L]
```

For clarification, if you want this URL below to show in your address bar

```
http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments/somefilename
```

Then the rule above should work. If payments is actually a file, i.e. payments.php then it would use this rule.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^local/accounts/([^/]+)$ /local/accounts/$1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi, will this hide the file name from the address bar ?

Comment: @user214292 yes, it does.

Comment: Hi, I'm calling `http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments/bacs.php`  what I want the address to show is 

`http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments`

Comment: What about your other PHP files besides bacs.php? What URL will they map to?

Comment: The first thing I gave you allows you to use ANY php file after payments. example `http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments/rent` will rewrite to  `http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments/rent.php` `http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments/anotherfile` will rewrite to `http://10.10.10.1/local/accounts/payments/anotherfile.php` etc